# Criar arrays de acordo com strings “explodidas”

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-6
    [1] => 1-7
    [2] => 2,9
)
```

Gostaria de agrupá-lo de acordo com o número inicial deles.

Exemplo de resultado (não tenho certeza desta sintaxe, mas é só para dar o exemplo):

```
Array

(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [] => 1-6,
        [] => 1-7
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [] => 2-9
    )
)
```

Como posso fazer isso?

OBS: Os numeros podem variar, pois são oriundos de registros dinâmicos. Pensei em criar diversos arrays manualmente, mas não posso, pois eles podem variar a qualquer momento.

Alguma ideia?

Tentei assim, mas sem resultados. Tentei explodir cada linha usando o separador "-", mas não descobri um meio eficiente de agrupá-los:

```
foreach($arrayCategorias as $key => $val){
    $exploded = explode('-', $key);
    $results[$exploded[0]][$exploded[1]] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Será isto:

```
$arrayCategorias = array( '1-6', '1-7', '2-9', '3-2', '3-5' );
$newArr = array();
foreach($arrayCategorias as $key => $val) {
    $num = explode('-', $val)[0];
    $newArr[$num][] = $val;
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($newArr), '</pre>';
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1-6
            [1] => 1-7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2-9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3-2
            [1] => 3-5
        )

)
```

Se quiseres as chaves pricipais reordenadas (`[0]`, `[1]` ...), depois do `foreach` podes fazer:

```
$newArr = array_values($newArr);
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/HGWvtO)

Comment: Quase lá, @Miguel! Consegue adaptar para um array sem ser multidimensional? ex: Cara, consegue adaptar isso para um array mais simples?

$arrayCategorias = array(
 '1-6',
 '1-7',
 '2-9',
 '3-2',
 '3-5'
);

Comment: Isso, este é formato original! Ele vem da aplicação. Passei o exemplo errado... vou corrigir.

Comment: Perfeito @Miguel, muito obrigado, e desculpe o equívoco do exemplo! Salvou uma vida aqui! ;)

Comment: haha de nada @MaykelEsser

Comment: @MaykelEsser cometi um pequeno lapso, desta meneira está mais correto

Comment: com seu ajuste, deu PARSE ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Comment: @MaykelEsser , deves ter algum erro de sintaxe: https://ideone.com/jpR6HI

Comment: Acho que `explode('-', $val)[0]` não funciona em algumas versões do PHP.

Comment: Nesse caso @MaykelEsser , coloque `$num[0]` em de colocar `[0]` onde faz explode. Obgado @Augusto

Comment: Obrigado @Augusto, tava revirando tudo aqui e não encontrava o problema! hahah, uso PHP 5.3.1. Obrigado novamente, @Miguel!